# inf of a finite set

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I often see the notation

$$\inf \{x_1,..,.x_n\}$$
or

$$\inf\{s,t\}$$

Is this considered appropriate notation or is it considered better to use $\min$ in these cases?

Comment: $\min$ is certainly more common in this case but I see nothing wrong with using $\inf$.

Comment: I would prefer $\min$, has a more concrete feel.

Comment: `inf` works for more cases, either inifity sets or finite sets. But for finite sets, I prefer `min`.

Comment: min comes as more specific when you have the "less than or equals to" ordering, and you refer to a pair of real numbers.  What sort of information and properties interest you and wish do you want to emphasize?

Answer (score 10):

Using $\mathrm{inf}$ is not incorrect, but may cause a moments pause when someone reads it.  Using $\mathrm{min}$ will not cause this pause.  Your goal should always be to communicate as effectively as possible so go with $\mathrm{min}$ unless you have a specific and compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the order you have on the set. Even with finite sets, an infimum can differ from a minimum. The infimum is the greatest lower bound while the minimum is an infimum belonging to the original set.

Take the set $\{0,1,2\}$ with the partial order $\prec$ defined by : $0\prec 1$ and $0\prec 2$. Then
$$ \inf \{1,2\} = 0 $$
but $\min\{1,2\}$ does not even exist.

Comment: I think this is an important point which some might not have considered. It's unclear (except possibly by the use of the [tag:real-analysis] tag) that the OP is talking about a well ordered set.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever you use it is okay, but there is a difference.

For min the result must be an element of the set while for inf that doesn't have to be the case.

$\inf \{ i\mid i = 1/2 ^ n\} = 0$

while $0$ is not part of the set

$\min \{ i\mid i = 1/2 ^ n\}$ is undefined because what is the lowest value in the set?

Answer (score 0):

um.there is no distinction between them,but I prefer min.

Comment: Taken literally this answer is contradictory: it is not possible to have a preference between things which are not distinct.  I think what you mean to say is that although both expressions denote the same real number, you *do* make a distinction between them and in fact prefer one over the other.  But in order for your answer to be more useful to others than "I like chocolate ice cream more than vanilla", I think you should explain *why* you prefer $\operatorname{min}$ over $\operatorname{max}$: otherwise you're just participating in an opinion poll.